# Can I use agar as a coagulant to make homemade tofu?

Tags: tofu, gelling-agents, soymilk

Good tofu is really hard to come by where I live, especially silken tofu. 
I want to try making my own tofu. There are tons of recipes online.
BUT, some of the coagulants (gypsum, or nigari) are also a bit hard to come by. I don't want to use epsom salts because they can cause a grainy tofu.

Will it be possible to use agar in this instance?

Comment: I have never made tofu, but why do you think that agar would be a coagulant at all? It's a very strange choice. \

Comment: You can find recipes that suggest using an acid (lemon juice etc.)...

Comment: I think if you use agar, you'll end up with soy Jell-O rather than tofu.

Comment: Have you tried epsom salts?  While different from gypsum or nigari, I don't find the result overly grainy.

Answer (score 3):

Agar is a gelling agent and will not work as a coagulant.  Give epsom salts a try.  I have not experienced the graininess that you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a soymilk jelly, which might or might not make a good component for desserts, but that is a distinct preparation from tofu, which works by coagulating the proteins in the soymilk itself instead of leaving the soymilk intact and incorporating it in a jelly.

Answer (score 2):

It will not have the same texture or taste as tofu which may be acceptable to you. It is very much a jelly/jello as pointed out by others. The biggest difference is that you will not be able to cook this gel-based tofu. For cold use, it would be fine. Agar will soften and melt when heated, melting point is concentration and acidity dependent but always well below boiling point of water.

If you have had some of the imitation almond tofu desserts in chinese restaurants, you can imagine the type of texture you would get.

Worth experimenting with it, just don't expect real tofu.